# Aluminium Beam - is it fit for purpose? Can it easily support this load?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, building-design, construction-management

I want to mount two patio heaters on my terrace in front of a window wall.  I cannot attach anything directly to the window wall so I am going to run an aluminium box beam between two brick columns.  The beam will be 5000mm long.  The beam dimensions are 80mm x 40mm with a 4mm thick wall, 13kg in weight.  The heaters weigh 6.5kg each and are 1000mm long.  They will be 1000mm from each end and therefore 1000 from each other.  I need to drill 8 x 8mm holes for mounting brackets (2 brackets per heater, 2 holes per bracket).

I am sure the beam will deflect a little - any serious risk of collapse?
[image: Patio Heater Attachment Points]
[image: Proposed Positioning]

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a "[homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832)" (notice the quotation marks). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: This is either a homework problem or something for which you should consult a structural engineer

Comment: The weight of the heaters is just a rounding error, compared with what happens when somebody decides to sit on the middle of the beam - or stand on it to clean the windows!

Comment: What is the maximum allowable bending stress of the aluminum you have?

Comment: Related: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/how-much-weight-can-an-aluminum-tube-beam-support?rq=1

Comment: Why don't you just hang on the beam. I assume that you weigh more than the heaters.  That should give you a good idea of what to expect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Load equations]

Using the 5th equation from the bottom the displacement is:

disp = Wa^3b^3/3EIL^3

We can superimpose it for each of your loads. Essentially your beam is loaded with 3.25kg (~33N) at 4 points (1,2,3,4m along).

I.e. disp(total) = disp(1st load) + disp(2nd load) ... + disp(4rth load)

For all the loads W = 33N

for the first and fourth a = 1 and b = 4
for the second and third a = 2 and b = 3

E = 69 x 10^9 (Elastic Modulus of Aluminium)

I = 7.11x10^-7 (Second moment of Area)

Ends up being:

disp = 0.001m

So at the middle x = 2.5

So displacement = 0.0025m

Sounds like it should be fine.

Comment: Technically shouldn't you use distributed loads, not point loads?

Comment: @JMac If the heaters are supported by brackets, and not actually touching the beam in between the brackets, the loads are not distributed. But since the OP didn't tell us which of the 80 and 40mm dimensions is the width and the depth of the beam, that would make a lot more difference than using point loads or distributed loads. And we don't know how the beams are attached to the brick pillars either.

Comment: As alephzero said - theyre bolted to the beam at defined points so it's definitely a point load. As for the beam orientation I just assumed he'd used the longest axis in the direction of loading and that the beam was bolted to the brick. I should probably have stated that explicitly.

Comment: Correct - I intent to have the longest axis be vertical. Beam will be bolted to brick with SS brackets.  May be some minor twisting force as heaters will be on face not below beam.

Comment: I added a more precise diagram that shows the exact points of loading, but I think as @ashgetstazered pointed out, the amount of deflection should be quite tolerable.

Comment: For a quick hand calculation I would just have applied all the load at the mid point of the beam span. That gives some safety margin, and if the deflection had been obviously too big there's no point in doing anything more accurate! Personally, I would still be inclined to put another brick pillar under the center of the beam - it just looks too inviting for kids to sit on, stand on, or even play at doing gymnastics on it, which will give much higher loads than the dead weight of the heaters.

Comment: @alephzero What does deflection have to do with OP's question, that is, whether the beam will collapse?

Comment: If the deflection was large then one could go onto use buckling equations. He (and I) were just trying to quickly get a feel of the situation.

Comment: @ashgetstazered Since there is no axial compressive force acting on the beam, it won't buckle in any way that you can easily calculate by hand.

Comment: @AndyzSmith Engineering common sense. If a simple calculation estimated the deflection in the middle as say 100mm, I don't care if it would "collapse" or not, it would most likely shake itself apart the first time there was a strong wind! Similarly, if it only deflects 1 or 2 mm, it's hardly worth bothering to calculate the stresses - experience says they are very unlikely to exceed the yield stress of the material. One of my mentors in industry often repeated the good advice, "if a design is no good, don't waste your time calculating exactly how bad it is to six decimal places."

Comment: @alephzero OP is not asking about dynamic loading.  Using the deflection to estimate the bending stress is unconventional, at best.  There are many cases of perfectly acceptable large deflection, where the bending moment create bending stress no where near the maximum allowable bending stress of the material.

Comment: This answer is woefully incomplete and fundamentally flawed in its assumtions about deflection being the controlling factor is the design.  A basic calculation of Bending Stress using the flexure formula and a Fixed Beam moment formula from the list is immediately indicated.  A simple comparison of this result to the maximum yield stress of the particular grade of aluminum/aluminum alloy that OP is using would be a thousand times better.

Comment: Added photo showing planned positioning - 2.5m high, above patio doors, below transom windows that open out.  Windows must clear beam.  The only possible additional weight might be a bird or squirrel, not a child.  May be some wind stress, as well as some twisting because weight will be on face, not below. I have asked the seller about the grade of aluminium.   If someone thinks 80x40x4mm not sufficient, I can either supersize to 100x50x6mm or add a catenary wire at the centre. But a deflection of 2.5mm seems tolerable and not indicative of imminent collapse... but I am not an engineer...

Comment: @JamesCotton My bet is that the brick wall plugs will fatigue or directly fail; their mount holes, with much less load that the maximum capacity of the beam.

Comment: The aluminium is 6082 T6 - Solution heat treated and artificially aged.  Also known as ISO: Al Si1MgMn.  Modulus of Elasticity 70 GPa.   Mounting to brick will be with 10no. SS screws at each end. @andyzsmith the brick is clearly the weakest substance in the whole setup.

Comment: @JamesCotton Fixed beam bending moment is given by Wab^2 / L^2.  Bending stress is given by Bending Moment * c / I.  I is given by http://www.engineersedge.com/calculators/section_square_case_10.htm

Comment: @JamesCotton Looks like aluminum you specify is 240 N / mm^2 ~= 30 KSI.

Comment: @JamesCotton I would estimate the horizontal tension on the top two screws would be approximately the tension in the top of the beam at that point which again is Wab^2/L^2.

Comment: @JamesCotton 6 kg is not a lot, but a meter is a long lever. Also, https://www.aircraftmaterials.com/data/aluminium/6082.html